# How to run ui5 commands in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, sapui5, ui5-tooling

I am trying to build the project using the command :

`ui5 build --all--`

which totally works fine , produces a `dist` in my local pc inside my project folder using terminal

Now in JENKINS (* FYI OS - WINDOWS) - which is running locally , configured to get the code from GIT ,

Here When I tried executing the same command in `Execute Windows Batch Command`

[image: It thrown err as :]

When I try executing `node` commands for suppose `node -v` it gave me the version

May I know why not the `ui5` doesn't work ? Am I required to do anything else here ?

I have tried executing CLI using the npm package manager:

```
npm install --global @ui5/cli
```

but still it shows me same err

Any help is much appreciated TIA

Answer (score 0):

You have to install ui5 globally (as part of your docker image) or if it's in your local dev dependencies(recommend) run `npm i && npx ui5 build`

Comment: sorry this didnt help ;(

Comment: strange, but on the other hand I have never seen any jekins windows-based-instance without docker agents... maybe upgrade your system to a more state of the art setting https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/using/using-agents/

Comment: sure i will try that ... thanks for the link :)